# Which layer should be reponsible for throwing exceptions in asp.net core web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Should a repository pattern throw an error if no data is retrieved?  I'm not convinced that it should or should i introduce a service layer

1. View
2. Controller
3. Repository Pattern
4. EF core

   ```
    public async Task<Customer> GetCustomerById(int id)
    {
        var result = await _dataContext.Customers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == id);

        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new KeyNotFoundException("Customer Not Found");
        }

        return result;
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case there is no need to throw an exception simply pass the result set as null and the controller will check if the result set is null it will return a NotFound response to notify the client that the requested resource is not present.